# When using traceroute -A, where does the ASN come from?

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface, bgp, networking

I haven't cracked open the source code yet, but I was curious which whois service the traceroute program uses to look up ASNs for a given IP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The copy running on my Linux box gets its answers from `198.108.0.18`. I was able to tell this by running `tcpdump` at the same time as running a `traceroute`.

The PTR records for that IP resolve to `rpsl-p.merit.edu`, and it happens that `whois.radb.net.` and `whois.ra.net.` point to the same IP address.

Further examination of the binary (with "`strings`") reveals that it's actually using the `whois.radb.net` hostname.  There's also a pair of (undocumented) environment variables (`$RA_SERVER` and `$RA_SERVICE`) which can change the host and port used for these queries.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: I ran tcpdump at the same time as a traceroute.

Answer (score 0):

Having not looked at the source code, I would suspect either [whois.ra.net](http://www.ra.net) or [riswhois.ripe.net](http://www.ripe.net/projects/ris/rawdata.html) or equivalent.